# Crear varios registros de base de datos relacionados en una misma vista

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo dos modelos en Rails, uno es Trabajador y el otro Asistencia. Un trabajador puede tener muchas asistencias y cada asistencia es de un solo trabajador.

Necesito crear una vista en donde me aparezcan todos los trabajadores en un each y que al lado de cada  trabajador me aparezca la opción de marcar un checkbox de boolean del modelo Asistencia, todo en una misma vista y que al momento de presionar guardar se creen todas las asistencias de los trabajadores al mismo tiempo.

Lo que he logrado es usar nested resources y agregar de la vista show de cada trabajador su asistencia para ese día , pero no he logrado lo que pregunte anteriormente. No se si crear una nueva vista, como mandar los datos del controlador a la vista, etc, espero su ayuda.

Estos son los modelos correspondientes:

```
class Worker < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report
  has_many :assistances, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :equip
end

class Assistance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :worker
  validates :fecha,uniqueness: { scope: [:worker_id] } 
end

create_table "workers", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "nombre"
  t.integer  "rut"
  t.text     "direccion"
  t.string   "telefono"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer  "equip_id"
end


create_table "assistances", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "worker_id"
  t.boolean  "asistio"
  t.boolean  "excepcion"
  t.date     "fecha"
  t.integer  "horas"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te separas ligeramente de las convenciones de Rails no debería resultarte difícil generar una estructura adecuada que leer en el controlador y enviar a tus modelos.

Cada uno de los checkboxes puede tener un nombre del estilo de  `asistencia[worker_id]`. El objetivo es mandar al controlador un hash como el siguiente: `asistencia => { worker_id_1: true, worker_id_2: false, (...) }`.

Así podrías generar un loop que lea este hash y vaya actualizando la asistencia de cada trabajador.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es un resumen de lo que creo que quieres hacer:

**Quieres poder crear muchas asistencias al mismo tiempo.**

Según entiendo, eso es todo, porque en la vista que te refieres no crearás los trabajadores. Solo quieres poder listarlos para elegir a cuáles de ellos les creas una asistencia nueva.

Para ello quieres una página en la que se listen todos los trabajadores junto a un ***checkbox***, y un botón de **"Crear Asistencias"** para que le cree asistencias a los trabajadores que marcaste con el checkbox.

**Solución:**

Puedes usar el **helper** genérico de *Rails* para crear el formulario:

```
<%= form_tag create_multiple_asistencias_path, method: :post do %>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Trabajador</th>
    </tr>
    <% @trabajadores.each do |trabajador| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "trabajadores_ids[]", trabajador.id %></td>
        <td><%= trabajador.full_name %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
  <%= submit_tag "Crear Asistencias" %>
<% end %>
```

Son fundamentales los corchetes `[]` junto a `trabajadores_ids` para que *Rails* sepa que se trata de un array de valores. Ese formulario asume que existe un método `create_multiple` (y su ruta) en el controlador **#asistencias**. Los creamos:

```
# En Routes.rb
# Versión usando Helper de rutas
resources :asistencias do
  collection do
    post 'create_multiple"
  end
end
# Opción básica
post "create_multiple", to: "asistencias#create_multiple"
```

El controlador:

```
class AsistenciasController < ...
  ...
  def create_multiple
    @trabajadores = Trabajadores.find(params[:trabajadores_ids])
    @trabajadores.each do |trabajador|
      trabajador.asistencias.create(asistio: true)
    end
    redirect_to donde_quieras_path
  end
```

Creo que no se me escapa nada y con eso debería funcionar.

**Bonus:** Como está arriba si falla en crear alguna asistencia (por alguna validación por ejemplo), la aplicación, no nos avisaría. Para ello podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
@trabajadores = Trabajadores.find(params[:trabajadores_ids])
@trabajadores.reject! do |trabajador|
  trabajador.asistencias.create(asistio: true)
end
if @trabajadores.empty?
  flash[:success] = "Se crearon todas las asistencias"
else
  flash[:danger] = "Fallaron las asistencias de #{@trabajadores.pluck(:full_name}"
end
redirect_to donde_quieras_path
```

Aclaración del bonus: El método `reject!` elimina de `@trabajadores` todos aquellos del bloque de `true` (los que se guardan correctamente). Por eso quedan en `@trabajadores`, solo aquellos que dieron `false` en el bloque (no se crearon).